# Sample an AM Demodulated Signal to Bits

Tags: rf, sampling, demodulation, automation

Is there a method for automatically sampling and converting an analogue signal into a series of bits?

I have an AM capture of a ceiling fan remote as a wave form, and so far I've been manually writing out the length of the high and low signals.

Is there an application, or other method (particularly for Arduino) that can do this for me more accurately?

Moreover, what prevents me from broadcasting my capture verbatim? I have a CC1101 chip – can it handle such an output (analogue audio)?

Comment: By 'AM' you mean OOK (On-Off Keying) right? What device are you using to receive and demodulate the rf signal? "...CC1101 chip – can it handle such an output (analogue audio)?" - does it have any analog audio inputs?

Comment: Ahhh AM demodulation setting in GQRX? It's a generic RTL SDR device from eBay (about $5). As for the CC1101 device, it has 8 pins: SCK, MOSI, GDO2, MISO, CSN, GDO0, VCC and GND.